# How do you put in percentage based margin to a CSS grid?

Tags: page-layout, css

I'm trying to learn how to build a grid system - and so far [this is what I've got](http://codepen.io/firefiber/pen/BKqwh). What I want to know is, how would I create actual gaps between the colums? If I put in a margin, everything goes out of the grid, because "box-sizing" only accounts for borders and padding. The only way I can think of doing it is to give every column a thick border.

Is there a way to get margins to work, so there's an actual space between the columns?

Comment: If you're going to use `margin` then you need to compensate by reducing the `width`

Comment: If you want your columns to be, say 20% wide, then if you want a gap, you need to remove that from the width. So, perhaps 18% width + 1% margins on each side.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With a smart but basic use of pseudo classes, you can easily get a great solution.

Let's assume your columns are using the class `.column` and you want 5 columns. That would be 20% each, minus a 2% gap (for example).

First of all, with `box-sizing: border-box;` you include padding and borders in the width as you mentioned, which is a fairly good practice.

```
.col {
box-sizing: border-box;
width: 18%;
margin-right: 2%;
}
```

After that, for the last `.col` we can use the pseudo class `:last-child` and override the right margin, like this:

```
.col:last-child {
margin-right: 0;
}
```

The numbers on this example don't actually crunch right, but it illustrates a good way of achieving what you want while using a scalable and maintainable CSS code.

**EDIT:** After reviewing your pen, I strongly advise against using the border to "separate" the columns. It's a visual *hack* and no more, one which actually depends on the background colour of your website. I recommend a detailed overview of how the "big shots" are doing it, such as **Bootstrap** or **Foundation**.

Comment: Thanks so much for this! Makes perfect sense! I was smashing my head on the wall the whole day yesterday trying to figure it out - I don't like using hacks either. It works perfectly now!